# Double tapping the UITab to scroll to the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am having some trouble with tapping the selected tab to make the tableview go to the top. I am using a custom TabBarViewController and inside there I am using the following function:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
static UIViewController *previousController = nil;
if (previousController == viewController) {
    // the same tab was tapped a second time
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollToTop)]) {
        [viewController scrollToTop];
    }
}
previousController = viewController;
}
```

I am also getting the following Error:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'scrollToTop'
```

I am wondering how I go about fixing this? If you guys need anymore information, please let me know. This has been bugging me for like a week!

Thanks all!!

Comment: Define a custom protocol with scrollToTop in it and add the protocol in headers of the viewControllers using it and make the method optional.

Answer (score 0):

Did your view controllers of tab bar controller is kind of UINavigationController?Maybe you should do like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    static UIViewController *previousController = nil;
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        if (previousController == ((UINavigationController *)viewController).viewControllers.firstObject) {
            // the same tab was tapped a second time
            if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollToTop)]) {
                [viewController scrollToTop];
            }
        }
        previousController = ((UINavigationController *)viewController).viewControllers.firstObject;
    } else {
        previousController = viewController;
    }
}
```